# Realizacion de una APP con PhoneGap y Framework7

Tags: javascript, phonegap, framework7

Estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación web haciendo uso de estas dos tecnologías, aunque en algunos puntos no logro entenderlo.

La aplicación presenta una pagina inicial de login, el cual hace una consulta a una API y si el usuario esta autenticado, pasas a un nuevo html en el que habrán distintas opciones.

Aqui una vista del `index.html`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- JQUERY -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Required meta tags-->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
 <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

 <title></title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7-icons.css">

 <!-- Path to Framework7 color related styles, Material Theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.colors.min.css">


 <script type="text/javascript" src='js/funciones.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Status bar overlay for full screen mode (PhoneGap) -->
    <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Panels overlay-->
    <div class="panel-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Left panel with reveal effect-->
    <div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
        <div class="content-block">
            <p>Left panel content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Views -->
    <div class="views">
      <!--Creamos el View principal-->
      <div class="view view-main">
        <div class="pages navbar-fixed">
          <!--Añadimos la primera página-->
          <div data-page="index" class="page">
           <!--Esto es barra superior, menu, logo, etc-->
            <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="center"><img src="lib/framework7/img/logo-f.png" width="60%;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--El contenido de la página-->
            <div class="page-content">

            <!-- FORMULARIO LOGIN -->
               <form>
                    <div class="list-block">
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="item-media"><i class = "icon icon-form-name"></i></div>
                            <div class="item-inner">
                              <div class="item-input">
                                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="DNI" id="textDNI">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="item-media"><i class = "icon icon-form-password"></i></div>
                            <div class="item-inner">
                              <div class="item-input">
                                  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="passWeb">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="item-content" style="padding-top: 3px;">   
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                  <div class="item-input">
                                      <a href="#" class="button button-raised button-fill color-green" id="btnLogin" onclick="IniSesion();">Iniciar Sesión</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>     
               </form>
            <!-- -->   
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/framework7/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>

    <script>
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

A continuacion, el archivo my-app.js, donde compruebo si la APP dispone de conexion a Internet:

```
var $$ = Dom7; //$$ para manipulación del DOM no es necesario jQuery pero si se utiliza no tendremos conflictos
myApp = new Framework7({
    material: true, //Activamos Material
    swipePanel: 'left' //Activamos la acción slide para el menú
});
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    dynamicNavbar: true,
    domCache: true //Activamos el DOM cache, para pages inline
});
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.init, false);

        document.addEventListener("offline", connectionOff, false);

        function connectionOff() {

                alert('No dispone de conexión a Internet. Si ella no podra hacer uso de la APP');
        }




    },
    init: function() {


    }


};
```

Y en este `js` tengo una función que conecta a la API y redirecciona a otra pagina:

```
function IniSesion(){

  if($('#textDNI').val() == ''){
      alert('Debe ingresar su DNI');
      return false;
  }

  if($('#passWeb').val() == ''){
      alert('Debe ingresar su contraseña');
      return false;
    }else{
       usuario = $('#textDNI').val();
       clave = $('#passWeb').val();

       var urlEnvio = ""

       /*Envio de peticion*/
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", urlEnvio, false);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("accept" ,"application/json");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type" ,"application/json");
      xmlhttp.send(urlEnvio);

      var resultado = xmlhttp.response;
      var long = resultado.length;
      var elementos =JSON.parse(resultado);

      if(elementos.count == '0'){
         myApp.addNotification({
                  message: 'Usuario o contraseña incorrecta',
                });
      }else{
         window.location.href = 'panelUsuario.html';
      }
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí parece ser que todo funciona correctamente, pero quiero establecer un calendario en el nuevo html y la documentación oficial de Framework7 me dice que que debo crear una instancia del calendario primeramente.

No se si esto debo hacerlo en el archivo `my-app.js` o crear otro nuevo o si se crea en un lugar diferente.